# `nvi` use contents of register in ex command

Tags: nvi

I'd like to be able to get the contents of a register in `nvi`, such as using

`b"wye` to yank a word into the `w` register and then invoke a shell command with the current word in it.

Currently, I have this command for running ripgrep (`rg`), but it's less than ideal in a number of ways.

It basically creates a new line below the current one with an `ex` command that runs the shell, deletes the new line into the `w` register and then runs the register via `@`.

```
" run ripgrep
map ^R mpb"wyeo^["wpI:!rg --color=always ^[A ^V| less -R^["wdd`p@w
```

Ideally, is there a way to refer to the contents of a register while typing out an ex command (similar to how `<c-r>w` would work in `vim`)?

Alternatively, is there a way to write arbitrary content to a register without touching the file you are currently visiting?

Comment: Are you constrained to `nvi` or are `vim` answer acceptable? Between vim’s scripting language (`:let @w = 'foobar'`) and the `<C-r>w` that you mention, it would be much easier to do.